# Regex matching certain subfolder and ignore its subfolder

Tags: regex, hive, regex-group

I am trying to using regex to match all folders that contain a `.Trash` file, but when we find a certain layer subfolder with `.Trash` then I don't want to match.

I am using `/[^/]+/*.Trash`, but it also matches the subfolder of `.Trash`.
How can I ignore subfolders?

For example:

```
/a/b/.Trash+other words -> good
/a/b/.Trash  -> good
/a/b/.blahTrash -> good
/a/.Trash -> good
/a/b/.Trash/c/d -> bad, because we already found /a/b/.Trash
```

Because `.Trash` can also be followed by other characters or numbers, so I can not use `.Trash` not followed by `/`.

Comment: Add `$` at the end to require string end.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. pls see my first example, because sometimes I have other characters following .Trash, so add $ doesn't match.

Comment: Try `^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]*Trash`, see https://regex101.com/r/fzAaAI/1

Comment: `/a/b/.blahTrash` does not contain `.Trash`, why is it good?

Comment: What version of regex are you using? If possible, it is simplest to do equivalent of `contains('.Trash') AND NOT contains('.Trash/')`

Comment: Can you please explain why `/a/b/.blahTrash` is "good" when it doesn't contain ".Trash"

Comment: I am writing a Hive query using regex. I think the reason it matches .blahTrash is because this . is not treated as a dot, but "any characters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+Trash[^\/]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lRp4lF/3/

```
/a/b/.Trash -> good
/a/b/.Trash+other words -> good
/a/b/.Trash  -> good
/a/b/.blahTrash -> good
/a/.Trash -> good
/a/b/.Trash/c/d -> bad
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is super close. But it only match /a/b/.Trash(with space or other characters) and if it's just /a/b/.Trash it doesn't match.

Comment: @RaeR: I have edited my answer, the new regex matches `/a/b/.Trash` as well, have a look at the link as well

Answer (score 0):

You may get some idea from this.

```
**(.*trash[^\/]+)**

Match 1
1.  /a/b/.Trash+other words -> good
Match 2
1.  /a/b/.Trash -> good
Match 3
1.  /a/b/.blahTrash -> good
Match 4
1.  /a/.Trash -> good
```

https://rubular.com/r/kGvbSIkHFfT9dM

Comment: Thanks, but this still got /a/b/.Trash/c/d. I wanna filter that.